# Checking active password is sufficient with DevicePolicyManager is crashed

Tags: android

```
Caused by java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: isUserRunning() from pid=13462, uid=101010 requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1683)
   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1636)
   at android.app.admin.IDevicePolicyManager$Stub$Proxy.isActivePasswordSufficient(IDevicePolicyManager.java:3714)
   at android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager.isActivePasswordSufficient(DevicePolicyManager.java:2003)
```

`public boolean isPasswordSufficient() {
       return mDpm.isActivePasswordSufficient();
    }`

Above is the crash log and method which caused this. The crash log is taken from a online crash reporting tool Crashlytics. As per the official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#isActivePasswordSufficient()) calling the isActivePasswordSufficient() method can throw SecurityException in 2 scenarios

- if the calling application does not own an active administrator that uses USES_POLICY_LIMIT_PASSWORD
- if the user is not unlocked.

And its seems that the first scenario will not happen as I have a mDpm.isAdminActive() check before calling the method also the device admin have

```
<device-admin>
    <uses-policies>
        <limit-password/>
```

in meta data. So I think this could be with the 2nd scenario. My question is what is this **if the user is not unlocked** means? and how could I reproduce the issue(if possible. I tried with creating multiple user and switched between the user account, also tried with screen lock enabled), and is there any way to handle this crash rather than adding try catch block(If its ok please tell me why)?. Also this crash is happened only with Motorola Nexus 6 Android 7.0 so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add  `android:protectionLevel="signature"` in to your manifest file

**As below** in to manifest file:

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
```

To know more about **[permission-element](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html)**

**Syntax:**

```
<permission android:description="string resource"
            android:icon="drawable resource"
            android:label="string resource"
            android:name="string"
            android:permissionGroup="string"
            android:protectionLevel=["normal" | "dangerous" |
                                     "signature" | "signatureOrSystem"] />
```

Comment: ND1010_ First thanks for your reply. But I do have some doubts with your answer, is the crash which occurred in my application is the lack of the permissions INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL ( I didint given this permission in my app) ?, also I couldn't find any official document related to this permission and is the permission is suppose to be declared in the client application manifest(I dont think so).

Comment: yes, your application will crash bcs of u have not put or apply permission request in to manifest file, i think you also very well know about this point

Comment: I couldn't see such permission in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html and when I write this into my app manifest its unresolved. Also this crash is happened only with one device so far(Update question) and this is not seen for the rest of the users. So I this must be not with the permission.I believe this is happening with multi user configuration I am also not able to reproduce it(There must some use case which caused this issue).

Comment: @VaisakhN please read my answer properly i have mention a link just click on and go through that link

Comment: @VaisakhN you should  have to give permission in to your application if your apk use potential risk implied in the permission